# How to convert this if-then-else to pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, closures

The following works:

```
fib n = let
       f k a b =
           if k==n then b
           else f (k+1) b (a+b)
    in f 1 0 1
```

but my attempt to rewrite the if-then-else to pattern matching, I get a warning about overlapping patterns and it produces wrong result (always 1)

```
fib n = let
    f n a b = b
    f k a b = f (k+1) b (a+b)
  in f 1 0 1
```

Why?

Or more generally, can you pattern-match as/in a closure?

Comment: I omitted the "fib 0 = 0" to avoid distraction

Comment: `n` in `f n a b` is not the `n` from `fib n`. It's a new one.

Comment: @Zeta: thanks, how can I make it a closure with pattern matching, or it cannot be done in Haskell?

Comment: Since you're not using `k` for anything except counting iterations, why not count down instead? Then you could match on 1.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yeah, I know, but I am cuorious about why this does not work (by the way, it is easier to convince yourself that the code works correctly if you count upwards since the fib numbers are generated "upwards" aswell)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is we can't write a pattern match to check that some arguments is equal to some variable. We can however, make two quick changes to make it so we can pattern match across a constant.

```
 fib n | n <= 0 = error "Out of range"
 fib n = go (n - 1) 0 1  -- I've renamed your [f] to the more common name [go]
   where go 0 a b = a    -- Base case
         go c a b = go (c - 1) b (a + b)
```

Now we're counting down instead of up which means we can pattern match at the base case of `0` instead of trying the awkward check of if `n' == n`. The first case of `fib n | ...` is just to check that we're being given a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like your second version using guards:

```
fib n = let
    f n' a b | n == n' = b
    f k a b = f (k+1) b (a+b)
  in f 1 0 1
```